# Initial Route Not working According to setsate value isCourse true in react native

Tags: react-native, setstate

Initial route not working according to setstate value after isCourse true but it's not going to work it's working like isCourse false. IsCourse is changed true in second useEffect but initial route not working for true

```
const [isCourse, setIsCourse] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleDynamicLinks = async () => {
      try {
        const link = await dynamicLinks().getInitialLink();
        if (link && link.url === 'https://englishmuni.page.link/course') {
          setIsCourse(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    handleDynamicLinks();
    const unsubscribe = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLinks);
    const themeListener = Appearance.addChangeListener(scheme => {
      setAppTheme(scheme.colorScheme);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
      themeListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsCourse(true);
  }, [isCourse]);
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName={isCourse ? 'Book': STACK_NAVIGATION_KEYS.HOME}
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor, size}) => {
          let iconName;
          if (route.name === 'MainHome') {
            size = focused ? imgSize : imgSize;
          } else if (route.name === 'LeaderBoard') {
            size = focused ? imgSize : imgSize;
            tintColor = focused ? '#051c60' : 'grey';
          } else if (route.name === 'Profile') {
            size = focused ? imgSize : imgSize;
            tintColor = focused ? '#051c60' : 'grey';
          }
          if (route.name === 'Book') {
            tintColor = focused ? '#051c60' : 'grey';
            size = focused ? imgSize : imgSize;
          } else if (route.name === STACK_NAVIGATION_KEYS.HOME) {
            tintColor = focused ? '#051c60' : 'grey';
            size = focused ? imgSize : imgSize;
          }
          return focused ? (
            <Image style={{width: size, height: size}} />
          ) : (
            <Image style={{width: size, height: size, tintColor: 'grey'}}/>
          );
        },
      })}>
```

Comment: remember that useState is asynchronous, so the tab navigator is rendered before the state changes,  you can try to create a function to render the tab. navigator or use a setimeOut to wait a few seconds before the return (Tab.Navigator )

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(() => {
   setIsCourse(true);
},[isCourse]);
```

This will set `isCourse` to true whenever `isCourse` changes value, it is really useless just remove it.

Now what will happend is that during the first render before `useEffect` runs, `isCourse` is `false` so it is expected that `initialRouteName` is equal to `STACK_NAVIGATION_KEYS.HOME` then when `useEffect` runs and set `isCourse` to `true` the component rerenders and `initialRouteName` is now equal to `STACK_NAVIGATION_KEYS.HOME`

That being said, now if you want to achieve the opposite you just initilize `isCourse` to `true` and set it to `false` inside the `useEffect` or just inverse the condition

```js
initialRouteName={isCourse ? STACK_NAVIGATION_KEYS.HOME : 'Book' }
```